# $.browser Undefined Seemingly Causing Faulty Page Display

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

At this [site](http://www.ultimatefijivacations.com/destinations/coral-coast/royal-davui-island-resort/) I have an error using the parent theme's `jquery.PrettyPhoto.js` This causes tabs not to load well nor gallery to work well it seems. The error states

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/decondo/lib/scripts/pretty/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=2.5
Line 59
```

I enqueued jQuery Migrate - v1.0.0 - 2013-01-14 with following code (whole function added): http://pastebin.com/EC3XrTiq

to the parent theme's function.php as I thought it would be related to an outdated jQuery function - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524289/browser-is-undefined-error -.

I found another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798403/typeerror-browser-is-undefined) at SE that suggested adding the $.browser function mentioning this function was no longer used since 1.3. The version loaded on those pages is 1.8.3 so this could be the issue then. Odd I did not have the issue earlier, but anyways.

<strike>I realized that jQuery migrate was not being loaded checking these pages in Firebug. I is located [here](http://www.ultimatefijivacations.com/wp-content/themes/decondo-child/lib/scripts/jquery-migrate.js) for sure though and would say the path is correct.</strike>

Thanks to to some more research and a check in safari using the inspector I did realise the jQuery migrate scripts is already loaded by WordPress.

Now the issue remains why the site's gallery (issues in Safari with layout), menu (dropdown broken in Firefox) and tabs (not loaded in Firefox) are not loading well and if the deprecated browser function is causing this or not.

Comment: Wordpress itself enqueues jQuery Migrate you don't need to enqueue it

Comment: **Update**

WordPress does load the jQuery Migrate script natively - found it in Safari using the inspector . Then I am still stuck solving this issue with prettyPhoto though. Not does it solve the breakdown of the gallery and tabs (in Firefox tabs are not loaded either). Nor could I find the Migrate script on the scripts list on this WP Doc page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

Comment: @sabarnix Yeah, thanks. Realized that. So no need for that. So what is causing the breakdown of the menu and tabs as well as gallery is still the issue. Do think those are javascript related, but even with debugging scripts turned on no other errors or warnings show up.

Comment: It seems superfish.js refuses to load in Firefox. It does load in Safari. This causes the dropdown issue. The tabs not showing well in FF is not clear yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is messing up your queue. Your jQuery URL has 1.8.3 version, while that is neither default in WP 3.9.1 or actual file it points to (1.11.0). Migrate is not showing up for me either, likely because of issues there.

Effectively you are missing `jQuery.browser` because it was removed in version 1.9+ and migrate is not loaded.

Comment: Yeah, it should be 1.11.0 and that one is loaded in Safari, but not in Firefox. Well it says 1.8.3, but loads 1.11.0 it seems actually.  And in FF superfish.js does not load either. Still trying to figure it out. In FF home is really broken now.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't say 1.8.3 for starters. You clearly have something interfering with core scripts there.

Comment: Seems to be my heavily customized NGG plugin got overwritten. This caused mayor havoc on the site. Seems to be doing better now, but server is really slow responding atm. DH is probably throttling RAM atm. Will check all again a little later.

Comment: Even with plugin replaced by old one the issue is returning. I do not see a jQuery loaded anywhere that has the string 1.8.3 added, but FF shows it again even though 1.11.0 is behind it. jQuery is enqueued and latest WP loads 1.11.0. Will keep on looking.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your site jQuery migrate is not enqueued as the version of jquery enqueued is 1.8.3 and jquery migrate only works with jquery version above 1.9 Probably your version of wordpress in not the latest one . The version of preetyphoto is outdated too you can use the latest version https://github.com/scaron/prettyphoto/blob/master/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js it do not use any $.browser.

Comment: Which version of wordpress are you using?

Comment: I am using WordPress 3.9.1 running deCondo child theme

Comment: It seems proper jQuery 1.11.0 is loaded when logged in and checking the frontend, jQuery migrate as well. But once logged off that is no longer the case. No jQuery Migrate loaded and jQuery 1.8.3 as attached version string although 1.11.0 is behind it. I know because I checked in Firebug under Net tab. Response shows 1.11.0.

Comment: The site seems to be working fine now even if I am not logged in.

Comment: Also this page http://goo.gl/Gju6Oy ? After I logged of and checked I did not see data in tabs nor a full dropdown menu

Comment: Never mind. Seems like it was a caching issue. Fingers crossed ;)